# C: error: array has incomplete element type 'void'

Tags: c, arrays, compiler-errors, void, void-pointers

**==> EXTREME BEGINNER QUESTION FOR EXTREME BEGINNERS <==**

Does anyone know why this: **`void buf[1];`** returns this error:

`error: array has incomplete element type 'void'`.

Is it normal ?

Comment: `void` is not a datatype. You have to declare an array as a valid datatype.

Comment: you cant have an array of void

Comment: @vasia has the answer you're looking for

Comment: @emsimpson92, the standard disagrees with you: "The `void` type comprises an empty set of values; **it is an** incomplete **object type** that cannot be completed" ([C2011 6.2.5/19](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p19), emphasis added).  The requirement is that the element type of an array must be a *complete* type, which `void` explicitly is not.

Comment: My mistake. I guess I've never heard of incomplete/complete types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`void` is not a complete type.  It is only used either in a function definition to state that it either takes no parameters or returns no value, or as a generic pointer i.e. `void *ptr`.

As such, a variable of type `void` cannot exist.

Answer (score 3):

You can't declare an array of void types - perhaps you meant to declare an array of void pointers? In this case you would do

```
void *buf[1];
```

However, it seems more likely you just want one void pointer?

```
void *buf;
```